# How to pass the values of Jelly foreach to javascript

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I need pass the values of jelly for each to a JavaScript array.

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define"
  xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form"
  xmlns:i="jelly:fmt" xmlns:p="/lib/hudson/project">

<script language="javascript">
    var list = new Array();
</script>

    <j:forEach var="value" items="${it.combo1}">
        <script language="javascript">
            list.push(${value})
        </script>        
    </j:forEach>
```

This line has an error: `list.push(${value})`

All this is in the creation of the Jenkins plugin. What can I do?